# Does has_many realation require foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wan to make simple `has_many` and `belongs_to` relation between my models.
I have `User` model and `Quote` model. And each quote belongs to user and evry user has many quotes.

I've studied this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

But I still don't know what about foreign key. Does Rails do it automatically in background (when I add `has_many` and `belongs_to`) or should I add manually migration with `user_id` column added to `Quotes` table?
Should I have `user_id` column in my `db_schema`?

Comment: No. Rails does not. but in migration of quote model before migrating the model to the database, you can specify `t.integer :user_id` so it can be treated as foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign keys should be defined in your migration. If you use the generator, Rails will generate a migration, which maybe looks like the following:

```
class CreateQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :quotes do |t|
      t.string :title, null: false
      t.text :content, null: false

      t.references :user
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The statement `t.references :user` will generate your foreign key column, which is called `user_id` in this case.

Here is a quote from the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one):

> Using t.integer :supplier_id makes the foreign key naming obvious and explicit. In current versions of Rails, you can abstract away this implementation detail by using t.references :supplier instead.